# Whirlpool Dryer powers on but won't spin

Tags: dryer, appliances, troubleshooting

My gas front-load Whirlpool dryer powers on but won't spin

- The blow fan spins fine
- The idler pulley seems to be fine, the belt is in tact and is tight.
  (though I did replace the idler pulleys wheel about 6 months ago due
  to deafening screeching noise)
- When I try to manually turn the drum there is A LOT of resistance,
  it's quite difficult to manually turn it
- Ocassionaly the dryer will start working on its own for a few more
  days until it stops spinning again. I've been having this issue for about 4 weeks

Is this a defective motor or a defective belt?
Or is there something else I can try?
Thanks!

My only picture at the moment, its of the idler pulley:[image]

Comment: Check the drum supporting rollers and associated bearings.

Comment: Take the belt off the motor and see if the motor spins... see if the drum drum spins easier

Comment: thanks for the input guys, I removed the top cover and noticed the belt wasn't completely straight and placed into the worn/discolored groove. I manually placed the belt back into that groove while rotating the drum manually and the dryer started to work again. Does this mean the belt is fine and just needed to be aligned or should I get a new belt anyway? Thanks

Comment: I would check for slack in that belt. If all is disassembled, it might be a good time to replace it if the belt is old and has slack/is loose.